# Pass variable in URL to another PHP page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass a variable from one php page to the next in an URL

Here is my example:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $MYURLPREFIX; ?>/gifts.html?category=novelty">Shop Now</a>
```

I then want to execute the appropriate array depending on what was passed in the query string.
So on my gifts.php I have:

```
if($SITE==SITE_MYSITE)
{
echo "<img src=\"images/gifts.png\" alt=\"Gifts Banner\">";
require_once("classfile.php");

if($SITE==SITE_MYSITE)
{
    $giftsArray=array(
        new gift('','10045'),
        new gift('','10048'),
        new gift('','10079'),
        new gift('','10103'),
        new gift('','10143'),
        new gift('','1024'),
        new gift('','10389'),
        new gift('','10452'),
        new gift('','10457'),
        new gift('','10515'),
        new gift('','10538'),
        new gift('','10540'),
        new gift('','10574'),
        new gift('','10616'),
        new gift('','10639')
    );
 }
}
```

I want to execute the above block if "novelty" was sent via the query string but I am not sure what the safest way to deal with the request.

What I have been trying to do, and which doesn't work is:

```
  if ($SITE==SITE_MYSITE) && (isset($category['novelty'])
```

Hope someone can help.  Cheers

Comment: Try this: `if(isset($_GET['novelty'])) { ... }`

Comment: Sorry as an update.... if(isset($_GET['novelty'])) && ($SITE==SITE_MYSITE).  This doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem. What happened when you tried it? Did you get an error message? Did you get incorrect results? Did you get *no results*? If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect? What were you expecting instead? Did you get *any* correct results? If so, what were they? Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such variable:

```
$category['novelty']
```

The query string values are in the `$_GET` collection where the key is the key being passed ("category") and the value is the value being passed ("novelty"), so you'd reference the value as:

```
$_GET['category']
```

This should contain the string value:

```
'novelty'
```

So you might do something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
    // a category has been specified
    if ($_GET['category'] == 'novelty') {
        // the specified category is "novelty"
    } else {
        // the specified category is something else
    }
} else {
    // a category has not been specified
}
```

The nested conditionals might get a little unwieldy, but you can organize and arrange the logic however you wish at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You did not define $SITE. So the condition fails to vlidate, other wise you can write
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
$category=$_GET['category'];
....
....
}